# LAMP on Knoppix

Tags: software-installation, apache-httpd, knoppix

I am trying to use the setup at [this link](http://ftp.free.fr/mirrors/ftp.knoppix.org/contrib/knoppix-webserver-setup/) to set up a LAMP server on my Knoppix USB drive. I have seen in multiple places that Knoppix comes with Apache, MySQL, and PHP; however I am unable to find anything of the sort. The setup from the link *requires* this to be present, as is evident by viewing the source code of `SETUP`. Should I install the needed packages manually, or is there some way to launch the builtin versions that I do not know of?

Note: `dpkg -l apa*` returns no packages and `dpkg -l http*` just returns some httptunneling package.

Comment: In general, instructions written 8 years ago are unlikely to still be correct or relevant (also indicated by the instructions saying to mount the floppy).

Comment: True. I had simply copied the files to a dir I created called /mnt/floppy.

Comment: But the question still stands, in multiple places there are indications that Knoppix has LAMP on it in multiple other places, or at least apache.